# proxy using curl and php

Tags: php, curl, proxy

i am using with curl libary to scrape web site.

when i am using proxy nothing now shown.

i took the ip proxy from hide my ass list.

here is my code. someone can tell me what is wrong ?

```
$url = 'http://www.sherut24.co.il';
$proxy = '189.218.145.44:10000';



$ch = curl_init();  // Initialise a cURL handle
// Setting proxy option for cURL

 
// Set any other cURL options that are required
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 
$results = curl_exec($ch);  // Execute a cURL request
curl_close($ch);    // Closing the cURL handle
echo $results;
```

Comment: Have you tried without proxy? What is the value of $results after request?

Comment: Should be `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "http://$proxy");` (you may also need to provide credentials for proxy authentication).

Comment: yes i tried , the result it html of the url.